# Older Home lots of 30 Amp Breakers on 12-2 Cable

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm troubleshooting some electrical issues in an older home.  There appears to be lots of circuits, all run with 12-2, that are protected by 30 Amp breakers.  I understand that this should be 10-2 according to modern safety code.

I'm wondering if this was done according to some other math?  or previous generation code?

Could have really been running 30 Amp loads on thinner than required copper with out any issues?

Options for improving safety?

Comment: If the devices on these circuits include normal (not 30A) outlets, you need to change the breakers to 20A or less. Which you need to do anyway if not changing out the wiring, but this was multiple-hazard-done-wrong if that's the case, as seems probable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

30 amp breakers must have 10/2 or larger wire is right.

In your case you should remove the 30 amp breakers and replace with 20 amp breakers.  12/2 is usually the largest wire you want for most home electrical devices(lights, outlets).  Imagine this what the panel powers.

Some people took the easy wrong idea that if a breaker/fuse tripped, that a larger breaker/fuse would fix the problem, or they had 30 amp breakers for a good price(still wrong).

All electrical devices(lights, stuff plugged into outlets) will only take the amount of amps they need to work, no more.  One light might take one amp.  A dryer will take 30 amps(usually less) and that is bad on 12/2 wire.  The problem happens there is a fault on the circuit that calls for 30 amps, but not enough to trip the breaker(causes fire).

Without knowing what the panel powers, maybe a few dryers, that need 10/2 or 10/3 and 30 amps, you might need to re wire, but I doubt that.

As for safety, since these breakers may have allowed loads in excess of 20A, each circuit should be audited for signs of stress.  Look at all devices and junction boxes, inspecting connections for signs of overheating.

Comment: You should also inspect **every** device and **every** junction on these circuits for signs of overheating - discoloration, melting, charring - and replace any that show any sign of that happening to them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  You're saying this because of the possibility that loads in excess of 20A may have been on those circuits and caused some damage?  I take that point and will do that.

Comment: @chad that's correct. There could have been significantly more than 30A on that #12 wire and the breaker wouldn't have tripped, but the wire would have overheated, possibly dangerously.

Answer (score 5):

### These are household circuits that *can't* be more than 20A.

Here's how I know.  I bought a bunch of 1-pole 30A breakers by mistake. Turns out, they **only have one** viable application:  small *Travel Trailers* powering a TT30 socket.

So unless this is an RV park, they don't belong in your panel. *I can tell*.

> There appears to be lots of circuits, all run with 12-2, that are protected by 30 Amp breakers. I understand that this should be 10-2 according to modern safety code.

No, other way 'round. The #12 or #14 cable is fine, but the breakers must be 20A or 15A respectively.

Since there are many breakers, this is clearly the common household circuits that serve lights, receptacles, and small appliances (dishwasher, disposal, microwave).  Those are required to be 15A or 20A.  However under NEC, all the 15A circuits are allowed to be 20A instead.  **They are not allowed to be larger than that** because then, the breaker will not effectively protect the appliance if it shorts out.

### This is the modern equivalent of "put a penny behind a fuse".

> I'm wondering if this was done according to some other math? or previous generation code?

No. This was never legal.

The person didn't like to bother thinking about amps, and liked to run two heaters (12A each) per circuit, or similar large loads. They got sick of breaker trips so on every single circuit they *defeated the overload protection* by slapping in **the largest 1-pole breaker that exists**. *(Good thing the fool hadn't realized you can put 120V circuits two at a time on a 2-pole breaker, or those breakers would all be 60s lol)*.

Of course, in doing so they also burned out their insurance coverage.  So they wasted thousands on insurance premiums that would not pay in the event of an electrical fire.

### Identify each wire as #12 vs #14.

And install *the correct breakers for your panel*.

Here's how to fail at that: look at the breaker you're pulling out and buy the same brand.  The last breaker might have been wrong.

Here's how to succeed: Look at the manufacturer of the panel, from the labeling (may be inside, on the backside of the deadfront cover where you'd never think to look lol).  Figure out the modern make of breakers for that panel.  Buy those breakers.

Westinghouse, Challenger type C, BRyant, Cutler Hammer 1" wide, Eaton 1" wide = Eaton BR

ITE, Gould, Murray = Siemens Q

Place 15A breakers on the #14 wire and 20A breakers on the #12.

### Inspect every box in every affected circuit.

Because overloading as much as 50% is just asking for hotspots on terminals or in the wires. Turn the circuits off and look for signs of stressed out wires or brittleness or burn damage on wire insulation near terminals.  Replace anything that doesn't look right. Often you can just get away with replacing a few inches.

Finger gymnastics are forbidden in Code. If you must shorten wires, you must put extensions on them so the wire comes out at least 3" beyond the surface of the wall. Do not squander wire length.  It must be easy to install switches and receptacles.

Whenever wiring is suspect, always shut the main breaker off.  Shutting off the individual circuit does not protect you if the wiring was done shoddy, or if **Multi-Wire Branch Circuits** (MWBCs aka shared neutral) circuits are not handle-tied - and most old ones aren't.  Nothing wrong with MWBCs, but they must be set up correctly and handle-tied for common maintenance shut-off.)

> Could have really been running 30 Amp loads on thinner than required copper with out any issues?

Not on every circuit, no.  There is a weird exception for certain motor and welder loads, but again, is it a combination RV park and welding shop?  The exception recognizes that nuisance trips happen from motor startup and short bursts of welder current. If you try the standard breaker and it generates nuisance trips, you can bump 1 size at a time (5 amps) until the nuisance trips stop happening, or you hit the max specified on the motor label or NEC 430. You are not allowed to just slap in the "max" breaker.

Comment: It's nothing to do with RV's  ... just an early 80s / late 70s basement finishing job.  I have a question about inspecting circuits for damage.  Is it adequate to simply see all the connections at switches, outlets, fixtures, junction boxes, panel etc?  If those are not showing signs of excess heat, I could fairly safely assume the cables of the circuit are okay, right?

Comment: @chad If you inspect the connections at junction and outlet boxes and everything looks OK - i.e. no burned/discolored insulation or connectors, you can probably assume the cable between connections is OK.  If you want to know more about the cable itself, you can have an electrician come out and use a megaohmmeter ("megger") to inspect the cable in more detail.

Comment: @chad if they are backstabs, those are concealed by the plastic and those will need to be pulled out and converted to side screws. Note that #12 wire does not fit on modern backstabs.   The sort of back-wire where you must loosen the screw to undo the wire, those are fine but must be taken apart to inspect. **Torque to spec** because torque matters.  10 inch-pounds is not too much, which is about where you "cam out" a Philips lol.  Most sockets also accept Robertson drive, that's the thing to use.